# Running an actix web server on a separate thread

Tags: rust, actix-web

I'm new to actix, and I'm trying to understand how I can run a server on one thread and send requests from another.

This is the code I have so far

```rust
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer};
use std::{sync::mpsc::channel, thread};

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = channel();
    thread::spawn(move || {
        let srv =
            HttpServer::new(|| App::new().default_service(web::to(|| HttpResponse::NotFound())))
                .bind("localhost:12347")
                .unwrap()
                .run();
        let _ = tx.send(srv);
    });
    reqwest::get("http://localhost:12347").await.unwrap();
    let srv = rx.recv().unwrap();
    srv.handle().stop(false).await;
}
```

It compiles just fine, but it gets stuck on on sending the request. It seems like the server is running, soI can't figure out why I am not getting a response.

EDIT: As suggested by @Finomnis and @cafce25,I changed the code to use tasks instead of threads, and `await`ed te result of `.run()`

```rust
use actix_web::{web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer};
use std::{sync::mpsc::channel, thread};

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = channel();
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        let srv =
            HttpServer::new(|| App::new().default_service(web::to(|| HttpResponse::NotFound())))
                .bind("localhost:12347")
                .unwrap()
                .run();
        let _ = tx.send(srv.handle());
        srv.await.unwrap();
    });
    reqwest::get("http://localhost:12347").await.unwrap();
    let handle = rx.recv().unwrap();
    handle.stop(false).await;
}
```

which solves the problem. I'm still curious if it is possible to do it on different threads since I can't use `await` inside a synchronous function.

Comment: Why on a different thread? Threading and `async` programming usually shouldn't be mixed (until a deep understanding of how `async` works is reached), instead spawn a new task.

Comment: The server would be very poorly implemented if it stopped running after the first request handled.

Comment: @cafce25 What do you mean with that?

Comment: Either you can handle requests in the thread and it never returns or the `requwest::get(...)` deadlocks cause the server doesn't handle requests yet. Or in other words they should follow your first suggestion @Finomnis.

Comment: @Finomnis Changing `thread` to `tokio`  (and slightly modifying the closure) still gives the same behaviour. So I don't think this is the source of the problem

Comment: @cafce25 I'm not sure I understand your feedback. Doesn't the server handle requests by returning a 404?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't return it to your rust code but to the request made. Also you have to `.await` the results of `.run()` for any listening to happen.

Comment: @cafce25 Thank you for all the feedback. Both examples should be syntactically correct now. I didn't post it as an answer since it doesn't solve my original question, which is how to achieve this on different threads

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? Because for all you know the runtime might as well put the server on a different thread from the request.

Comment: You should not use synchronous channels in asynchronous code (although I don't know if that's your problem).

Comment: *"which is how to achieve this on different threads"* - you can't and shouldn't - the `HttpServer` itself already does multithreading internally. Moving it onto a different thread will give you no performance benefit. As mentioned earlier, move it to a task instead. Not on a tokio task, though - `#[actix_web::main]` has its own runtime. You need to spawn an actix-web task instead. Of course you can use the `#[tokio::main]` runtime instead if you want to spawn tokio tasks. `actix-web` is compatible with that.

Comment: Read the documentation of `run()`: `This method starts a number of HTTP workers in separate threads.`. You don't need to put it on a thread yourself, just `spawn` the result of `run()`. And no, you cannot go from asynchronous to synchronous and back to asynchronous. Once you are in synchronous land, you have no good way of returning back to async.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code; the biggest one being that you never `.await` the `run()` method.

For that fact alone you cannot run it in a normal thread, it has to exist in an async task.

So what happens is:

- you create the server
- the server never runs because it doesn't get `await`ed
- you query the server for a response
- the response never comes because the server doesn't run, so you get stuck in `reqwest::get`

What you should do instead:

- start the server.

Also:

- You don't need to propagate the server object out to stop it. You can create a `.handle()` **first** before you move it into the task. The server handle does not contain a reference to the server, it's based on smart pointers instead.
- **NEVER** use synchronous channels with async tasks. It will block the runtime, dead-locking everything. (The only reason it worked in your second example is because it is most likely a multi-threaded runtime and you only dead-locked one of the runtime cores. Still bad.)
- (Maybe) don't `tokio::spawn` if you use `#[actix_web::main]`. `actix-web` has its own runtime, you need to `actix_web::rt::spawn` with it. If you want to use `tokio` based tasks, you need to do `#[tokio::main]`. `actix-web` is compatible with the tokio runtime. (**EDIT**: actix-web *might* be compatible with `tokio::spawn()`, I just didn't find documentation anywhere that says it is)

With all that fixed, here is a working version:

```rust
use actix_web::{rt, web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer};

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() {
    let srv = HttpServer::new(|| App::new().default_service(web::to(|| HttpResponse::NotFound())))
        .bind("localhost:12347")
        .unwrap()
        .run();
    let srv_handle = srv.handle();

    rt::spawn(srv);

    let response = reqwest::get("http://localhost:12347").await.unwrap();
    println!("Response code: {:?}", response.status());

    srv_handle.stop(false).await;
}
```

```
Response code: 404
```

Comment: I think actix is compatible with `tokio::spawn()`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! This really helped things "click" for me :)

Comment: @ChayimFriedman It seems like it, but it isn't specified anywhere to my knowledge. And as actix provides its own `spawn` method, I think it's better to use that one. But of course it might be compatible, so I really don't know.